InterruptedException in Sping
I have a spring Controller that calls a Service, who uses the command line to zip or unzip with 7zip (this is an external requirement, has to be 7zip from command line)
Here is a simplified method:
public File zipDirInPlace(File backupDir, int timeoutTime, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    log.info("Zipping Folder {}", backupDir.getAbsolutePath());
    File zipDir = new File(backupDir.getPath() + ".zip");
    String[] command = { sevenZip, "a", zipDir.getAbsolutePath(), backupDir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\*" };
    // Create a process builder
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    // Start the process
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info("7Zip claims: {}", line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error reading process output", e);
    }
    // Wait for the process to complete
    try {
        if (!process.waitFor(timeoutTime, timeUnit)) {
            // If time has passed, kill it.
            process.destroy();
            // If it is not killed in 1 minute again with more force.
            process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            process.destroyForcibly();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Running 7zip was interrupted", e);
        // Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); ??
        throw new InterruptedException(e);
    }

    int exitCode = process.exitValue();

    // Check the exit code
    if (exitCode == 0) {
        log.info("Packing completed successfully");
    } else {
        log.error("Could not zip {}", exitCode);
    }
    return zipDir;
}

The expected behavior is this:
Pack the zip, and if the process takes longer then the 10 Minutes, kill it.
Once the process is killed, the controller takes the InterruptedException and returns a custom error response:
catch (InterruptedException e) {

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,

                "Something went wrong using 7zip from command line", e);

    }

The problem:
Sonar complains that the controller does consume the Exception without re-throwing it or interrupting the thread.
However:
a) re-throwing it does not make sense since the controller will not return the custom http message then.
b) interrupting the thread which, would be either the controller or the service thread depending on where it happens and how spring works internally, does not seem like a smart move. (See Interrupt Sping Thread)
How do I deal with the exception properly?
Do I have an error in understandinf what Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); does?

Just a side note and not sure if that's what your actual code looks like: in what you posted throw new InterruptedException(e); would be unnecessary because e is already an InterruptedException so throw e; should be enough.

You want to inform the thread that it needs to be interrupted, regardless if you created it or not (to release threads etc.). In this case it is a thread from the process so basically one you created anyway. Also what is the point of new InterruptedException(e) instead of just re-throwing it? another option is to just not catch the exception in the controller and let the Spring error handling handle it. You can wrap the exception to include your custom message which would be used by the spring exception handling (or just write an @ExceptionHandler in this controller to handle this case.

@Thomas yes, you are right.

To satisfy Sonar just add remove the catch in the controller and instead write an @ExceptionHandler instead in the controller.
@ExceptionHandler(InterruptedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Something went wrong using 7zip from command line")
public void handleInterrupt() {}

Which should yield the same end result but satisfies Sonar as you now removed the catch clause, you could remove it in the service as well.
